# Why is Vert.x called responsive even though it is single threaded

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, vert.x

What I understood from Vert.x documentation (and a little bit of coding in it) is that Vert.x is *single threaded* and executes events in the *event pool*. It doesn't wait for I/O or any network operation(s) rather than giving time to another event (which was not before in any Java multi-threaded framework).

But I couldn't understand following:

1. How single thread is better than multi-threaded? What if there are millions of incoming HTTP requests? Won't it be slower than other multi-threaded frameworks?
2. Verticles depend on CPU cores. As many CPU cores you have, you can have that many verticles running in parallel. How come a language that works on a virtual machine can make use of CPU as needed? As far as I know, the Java VM (JVM) is an application that uses just another OS process for (here my understanding is less about OS and JVM hence my question might be naive).
3. If a single threaded, non-blocking concept is so effective then why can't we have the same non-blocking concept in a multi-threaded environemnt? Won't it be faster? Or again, is it because CPU can execute one thread at a time?

Comment: why do you think Vertx is single threaded?

Comment: Your second point directly contradicts your claim that vert.x is single-threaded

Comment: #3 is incorrect as well. There is nothing stopping you using non-blocking I/O in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 1):

> What I understood from Vert.x documentation (and a little bit of coding in it) is that Vert.x is single threaded and executes events in the event pool.

It is event-driven, callback-based. [It isn't single-threaded](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_in_the_beginning_there_was_vert_x):

> Instead of a single event loop, each Vertx instance maintains several event loops. By default we choose the number based on the number of available cores on the machine, but this can be overridden.
>
> It doesn't wait for I/O or any network operation(s)

It uses non-blocking or asynchronous I/O, it isn't clear which. Use of the Reactor pattern suggests non-blocking, but it may not be.

> rather than giving time to another event (which was not before in any Java multi-threaded framework).

This is meaningless.

> 1. How single thread is better than multi-threaded?

It isn't.

> What if there are millions of incoming HTTP requests? Won't it be slower than other multi-threaded frameworks?

Yes.

> 2. Verticles depend on CPU cores. As many CPU cores you have, you can have that many verticles running in parallel. How come a language that works on a virtual machine can make use of CPU as needed? As far as I know, the Java VM (JVM) is an application that uses just another OS process for (here my understanding is less about OS and JVM hence my question might be naive).

It uses a thread per core, as per the quotation above, or whatever you choose by overriding that.

> 3. If a single threaded, non-blocking concept is so effective then why can't we have the same non-blocking concept in a multi-threaded environemnt?

You can.

> Won't it be faster?

Yes.

> Or again, is it because CPU can execute one thread at a time?

A multi-core CPU can execute more than one thread at a time. I don't know what 'it' in 'is it because' refers to.

Comment: Even if there are millions of requests coming in it all depends on how you scale horizontally. Vertx is the basis of server in Quarkus framework and it easily scales to any number you want. Ideally you would want to reactively scale based on load using KEDA Http add on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Vertx isn't single threaded by any means. It just doesn't spawn more threads that it needs.

Second, and this is not related to Vertx at all, JVM maps threads to native OS threads.

Third, we can have non-blocking behavior in multithreaded environment. It's not one thread per CPU, but one thread per core.
But then the question is: "what are those threads doing?". Because usually, to be useful, they need other resources. Network, DB, filesystem, memory. And here it becomes tricky. When you're single threaded, you don't have race conditions. The only one accessing the memory at any point of time is you. But if you're multi threaded, you need to concern yourself with mutexes, or any other way to keep you data consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Q:

> How single thread is better than multi-threaded? What if there are millions of incoming HTTP requests? Won't it be slower than other multi-threaded frameworks?

A:

Vert.x isn't a single threaded framework, it does make sure that a "verticle" which is something you deploy within you application and register with vert.x is mostly single threaded.

The reason for this is that concurrency with multiple threads over complicates concurrency with locks synchronisation and other concept that need to be taken care of with multi threaded communication.

While verticles are single threaded the do use something called an event loop which is the true power behind this paradigm called the reactor pattern or multi reactor pattern in Vert.x's case. Multiple verticles can be registered within one application, communication between these verticles run through an eventbus which empowers verticles to use an event based transfer protocol internally but this can also be distributed using some other technology to manage the clustering.

event loops handle events coming in on one thread but everything is async so computation gets handled by the loop and when it's done a signal notifies that a result can be used.

So all computation is either callback based or uses something like Reactive.X /  fibers / coroutines / channels and the lot.

Due to the simpler communication model for concurrency and other nice features of Vert.x it can actually be faster than a lot of the Blocking and pure multi threaded models out there. 
[the numbers](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r18&hw=ph&test=plaintext&l=zik0ov-f)

Q:

> If a single threaded, non-blocking concept is so effective then why can't we have the same non-blocking concept in a multi-threaded environemnt? Won't it be faster? Or again, is it because CPU can execute one thread at a time?

A:

Like a said with the first question it's not really single threaded. Actually when you know something is blocking you'll have to register computation with a method called `executeBlocking` which wil make it run multithreaded on an `ExecutorService` managed by Vert.x

The reason why Vert.x's model is mostly faster is also here because event loops make better use of cpu computation features and constraints. This is mostly powered by the Netty project.

the overhead of multi threading with it's locks and syncs imposes to much strain to outdo Vert.x with it's multi reactor pattern.